# How do I find when textview ends and bounces?

Tags: ios, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` and a `UIButton` in the storyboard. 
I want to find a way to know if the `UITextView` reaches the end and bounces and then button would appear next.
I tried to do this with `UITextRange`, `UITextPosition` and `CGRect` objects but it didn't work and on other side it's not the method that I prefer. Any Ideas on how to do this?!

Answer (score 1):

`UITextView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`, so you can use the `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol to observe the changing bounds thus informing you when it reaches the end.